# Apple Developer Enterprise Licence how many apps can we distribute?

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise

For internal beta tests we would like to implement a system to automaticly distribute our signed apps.

According to our information we need to have an enterprise licence to accomplish this.

We are working on multiple projects each with a different package name.

Are we able to sign multiple apps with a single enterprise licence?

The information we are finding is contradicting. One persons says there is no limit on the amount of app(-packagenames) we are able to sign. The other says it's limited to two distribution profiles.

If there is a limit, are we able to use a wildcard?

So in short:

We researching if an enterprise licence covers our means. We want to enroll the enterprise program to let a CI sign multiple apps. Apps have different package names.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on how many App ID-s you have on any one Program, either Enterprise or Developer, i have used 6 and more, and been a part of the teams that have used more than 25. 
In short, Enterprise Program is for enterprises for their In-House applications that are not intended to distribute outside of the enterprise, if You want to distribute your finished App outside of your enterprise you will need a Developer program. 
For testing apple has https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ system that is for beta testing, and is available in all programs.